# How to read each frame from a movie file in android?

Tags: android

My application want to read each frame from a movie file and used to other.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there's a way to do this using the built-in decoders (but would be glad to hear of it if there is).  You might have to make something based on modifications to the alternative software decoder included in the android sources, or an external alternative such as ffmpeg or mplayer.